# React query not refetching the updated data after deletion in my production build, in next js 13.4

Tags: reactjs, next.js, prisma, react-query

My app is using nextjs 13 with react query 5
when i delete an item from a list , in development build the list is refetched on every deletion, but in production build the list is not being refetched and the state is being persited.
here is my code :

```
"use client";
import { deleteFIBData, getFIBList } from "@/app/hooks/FIBqueries";
import { useMutation, useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import Link from "next/link";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { toast } from "react-hot-toast";

type Props = {};

const FIBList = (props: Props) => {
    const {
        isLoading: isListLoading,
        error,
        data: fibData,
        refetch: refetchFIBList,
    } = useQuery({
        queryKey: ["FIBActivitiesList"],
        queryFn: getFIBList,
    });

    const deleteFIBDataMutation = useMutation({
        mutationFn: deleteFIBData,
        onSuccess: () => {
            refetchFIBList();
            toast.success("Successfully deleted!");
        },
    });

    if (isListLoading) {
        return (
            <div className="w-full h-full flex justify-center items-center">
                Loading ...
            </div>
        );
    }

    if (deleteFIBDataMutation.isLoading) {
        return (
            <div className="w-full h-full flex justify-center items-center">
                Loading ...
            </div>
        );
    }

    console.log("data", fibData);

    return (
        <div className="p-5">
            <div className="relative overflow-x-auto">
                <table className="w-full text-sm text-left text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
                    <thead
                        className="text-xs text-gray-700 uppercase bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-700 
                        dark:text-gray-400">
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col" className="px-6 py-3">
                                Question
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" className="px-6 py-3"></th>
                            <th scope="col" className="px-6 py-3"></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {fibData?.map((data: any, index: number) => {
                            return (
                                <tr
                                    key={index}
                                    className="bg-white border-b dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
                                    <th
                                        scope="row"
                                        className="px-6 py-4 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap 
                                dark:text-white">
                                        {data.questions.join(" ")}
                                    </th>
                                    <td className="px-6 py-4">
                                        <Link
                                            className="w-full h-full"
                                            href={`/dashboard/fillInTheBlanks/edit/${data.id}`}>
                                            Edit
                                        </Link>
                                    </td>
                                    <td className="px-6 py-4">
                                        <div
                                            className="w-full h-full cursor-pointer"
                                            onClick={async (e) => {
                                                e.preventDefault();
                                                await deleteFIBDataMutation.mutateAsync(
                                                    {
                                                        id: data.id,
                                                    }
                                                );
                                            }}>
                                            Delete
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            );
                        })}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default FIBList;
```

I tried refetching the fibdata after the deletion using:

```
onSuccess: async () => {
            await refetchFIBList();
            toast.success("Successfully deleted!");
        },
```

and this works in developement build, but when i create a prod build , then it suddenly stop working, even though the deletion happens in the db from production .

Answer (score 0):

It’s possible that the issue you are experiencing in production is related to caching. You could try setting the staleTime option of the useQuery hook to a lower value or even to 0 to disable caching and see if that resolves the issue. Another thing you could try is to set the cacheTime option of the useQuery hook to a lower value or even to 0 to remove inactive queries from the cache immediately.

Comment: Already did that ,
What i actually ,think is my list page is being made static , and the page is being baked with the latest data that is available during the build time.
But what Im unable to comprehend is that during in my prod build ,why is the page not being able to refetch when their is some change in the db.

Comment: it could be due to the way your list page is being generated. One way to solve this issue is to use Next.js’s Incremental Static Regeneration (ISR) feature. With ISR, you can statically generate individual pages at build time, and then update them in the background as traffic comes in. This allows you to serve static pages that are always up-to-date with the latest data from your database.